# AngularJS Iframe pop window like fancybox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a web application using the AngularJS and PHP. I want to open a pop-up by passing a few params and render a new page in the pop-up.
How can I open a fancy-box like i-frame pop-up in AngularJS ?

Comment: Is the solution reside in the 
thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812203/angularjs-show-popups-the-most-elegant-way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do pretty much anything using [`AngularUI` library](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). Here's [working fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/6UTtgqUcRFp4vWH9BnGk?p=preview) for it.

Sample code would be:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">    
    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'some-dynamic.php',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};
```

**some-dynamic.php**

```
<?php
echo "Some <b>html in</b> the modal";
```

Of course you should change the code above before you have fully working example.

Comment: cab u please check your fiddle http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview i think u have missed typed it .

Comment: Sure :). Anyway it's the standard fiddle from AngularUI so you still have to do code changes like I suggested.