# how to create pop up screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I am using JQM from last one year. I have developed a pop up screen In jqm [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p943a/). Can we develop this type of pop up screen in angular js? It means open a pop up screen when button is click. With edit field and button in that?

```
$(function(){
  $('#openPopup').click(function(){
      $( "#testCaseId" ).popup( "open" );
  })
})
```

Comment: There are a million directives out there doing this, and it's been answered in many posts/questions. Check out angular-ui bootstrap for starters.

Comment: Here is question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812203/angularjs-show-popups-the-most-elegant-way

Comment: already use bootstrap but no pop up is found

Comment: Google? http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/#

Comment: thank ...can any body use fiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular-ui-bootstrap is port of bootstrap re-written in angular...

you can checkout this plunker on [how to create modal popup](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcZc4UcU6eikCct5IpzA?p=preview)

to learn how to create other bootstrap components in angularjs checkout [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
```

Comment: Harish can you use fiddle or jsbin for example

Comment: i have provided plunker links in the answer

Comment: plunker is showing error can you please provide fiddle

Comment: Hello Plunker! is written in that..

Comment: check out [new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xcZc4UcU6eikCct5IpzA?p=preview)

Comment: after loading it show ..error in plunker..

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xcZc4UcU6eikCct5IpzA?p=preview - its working for me

Comment: I need to to login ? actually never use plunker.used only fiddle and jsbin

Comment: plnkr.co/edit/xcZc4UcU6eikCct5IpzA?p=preview  link is working for me ..

Comment: finally.. its working.. you can just copy paste the code from here to jsbin or whereever you want... i have put in effort to do something and its your turn... be ready to learn please...

Comment: thanks ..mean I need to lear bootstrap before angular.js ?

Comment: angularjs is javascript framework... bootstrap in for display purpose... just go thru egghead.io videos, you will learn both

Comment: @user3665790 so you have downvoted everyone who tried to help you, great man... really great...

Comment: I didnot do down voted..

Answer (score -1):

Its fairly straight-forward to leverage [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to create your modal popup:

**Modal Directive**

```
app.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'modalTemplate.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.id = attr.id;
            scope.title = attr.title;
            element.removeAttr('id');
        }
    }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <div title="This is the modal title" id="myModal" modal>
        This is the modal content
    </div>
</body>
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4x1IxY3Fev2Bv6kwhVZR?p=preview)

Comment: pluker is showing error can you use fiddle..

Comment: Hello Plunker! is written in that

Comment: after loading it show ..error in pluker..