# AngularJS : render a view in a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, dialog

I'm quite new to AngularJS, what I want to do is simple :

After a click, open a jQuery dialog and Render a view inside it, for example I want this inside my popup :

```
<div ng-controller="myController">{{dummy}}</div>
```

This partial must come via an Ajax Request (not already present somewhere in the page) and be rendered in a jQuery Dialog.

I saw some examples with the $modal service ([AngularJS, show popups - The most elegant way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812203/angularjs-show-popups-the-most-elegant-way)), but here I need jQuery's dialog.

To summarize I want to do the same as the $modal service but in / with a jQuery Dialog instead, Thank you for your help.

Comment: What did you tried ? Show us some effort and post your approach in order to help you.

Comment: You should probably create a directive to do this, but why do you "need" a jquery dialog? is it a styling thing? I find it a lot easier to stick to one library rather than mix and match their components