# How to remove a click binded to $document

Tags: angularjs

I have a popup that i want to close when clicked anywhere else on screen, I do this by triggering `$document.bind('click',function(){...});` inside the open function `$scope.open = function(){...}`.

I also have another function for close `$scope.close = function(){...}`

The objective is to remove the bind inside the close function.

I am new to angular and  so unfortunately I dont fully understand the answers I've found on this questions. Theoretically, I know I might be able to achieve this with `$destroy`, but I have no idea how to physically implement it. Can someone please teach me how to do this?

EDIT: I am doing this in controllers & directives.

Comment: Don't manipulate DOM within a controller. You must have come across that in your reading about Angular? Assume that a controller has no clue that DOM exists.

Comment: The OP never mentioned a controller. Maybe he/she is using the link function?

Comment: @NewDev that makes sense but unfortunately I don't know any other way to close a popup. Can you recommend anything?

Comment: @seldary I am using this in controllers and directives, so its getting pretty messy.

Comment: @muudless, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812203/angularjs-show-popups-the-most-elegant-way

Comment: @NewDev Thank you for the resource, I've read that during my research and understands it theoretically, but unfortunately don't know how to implement it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the popup shows, do:

```
$document.on('click', documentClick);
```

and in `documentClick` hide the popover, and do:

```
$document.off('click', documentClick);
```

If you encapsulate the popup behavior in a myPopover directive, define these in the link function of the directive. Don't manipulate the DOM in the controller function of the popover directive, and don't do that in a general controller of a page.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've moved the elements into a directive and applied your suggestion and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

you can unbind event with the method `unbind()`

```
$document.unbind('click');
```

will remove your event handler

refer to [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) documentation

Comment: This will also unbind other handlers, which might break other functionality, defined elsewhere.